# How many records we can easily Get in asp.net Treeview Control from server side on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, webforms, treeview

How many record we can easily fetch in below **TreeView control**, suppose 1000 records **OR** 2000 records **OR** how much ??

```
<asp:TreeView
        ID="TreeView1" runat="Server" />
```

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

[According to Microsoft:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529261.aspx)

> Rendering enormous hierarchical data sets in a single TreeView data
>   island is not recommended. As a general rule, try to keep the number
>   of nodes in a tree under 1000.

So I think there is no limit, but you will get huge performance issues if you go over 1000. This is like what microsoft recommends you..

Comment: Thanks to reply, how i can fetch records more than 10,000 in treeview form, with good performance.

Comment: I think it is not possible, if Microsoft says that you need to try to keep the records under 1000. You will have huge performance issues if you go for 10x of that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have get solution for that problem, that is populate tree on demand, it works well for me.